# Getting information on my usb devices

Tags: usb

There used to be lots of info on usb devices, coming form /proc/bus/usb/devices.

Then this was no longer auto mounted, so you had to mount it yourself (usbdevfs it was called, or something)

Now, in 11.04, even that doesn't work. How can I get some info on my device now?

Comment: define what info you want and I'll expand my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`lsusb`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/lsusb.8.html) shows this:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0138 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:c218 Suyin Corp.  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

What more do you need to know?

If you need more there is `usbview` on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/usbview/):  USBView is a GTK program that displays the topography of the devices that are plugged into the USB bus on a Linux machine. It also displays information on each of the devices. This can be useful to determine if a device is working properly or not.

[image]

<sub>did not try usbview in 11.04 btw</sub>

Answer (score 5):

`/proc` is becoming deprecated, `/sys/bus/usb/devices` is what you are looking for. A program to query for USB devices is `lsusb`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few nice tools for gathering USB info about connected devices,

`usb-devices`:

This is part of the **DEFAULT PACKAGE** `usbutils` on 18.04 LTS.  Specimen output:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.15
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.15.0-1050-oem xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0781 ProdID=5571 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=SanDisk'
S:  Product=Cruzer Fit
S:  SerialNumber=4C530000280331109123
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
```

.

`udevadm monitor`

`udevadm` is part of the **DEFAULT PACKAGE** `udev` on 18.04 LTS.

Execute this command **BEFORE** you connect your USB device.

Note in the specimen  output below it tells us which block device the USB flash drive loaded as:

```
udevadm monitor
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[969.010067] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[969.010367] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[969.018769] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
KERNEL[969.018849] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[969.018934] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[969.019049] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [969.024995] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
UDEV  [969.031390] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [969.036362] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0 (scsi)
UDEV  [969.041258] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/scsi_host/host0 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [969.046202] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [969.051734] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1 (usb)
KERNEL[970.051706] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[970.052068] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[970.052215] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[970.052435] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[970.052585] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[970.052774] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[970.052963] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [970.060833] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[970.061634] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [970.069006] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [970.071467] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:0 (bdi)
UDEV  [970.075852] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_disk/0:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[970.079839] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
KERNEL[970.079989] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
UDEV  [970.083556] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [970.091288] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_device/0:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [970.091755] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg0 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [970.106807] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/bsg/0:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [970.339976] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda (block)
UDEV  [970.519549] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda/sda1 (block)
```

Comment: @user68186 Please validate your info before down-marking a **correct** answer. I  checked BOTH pkgs are part of the furniture of a default 18.04 LTS install using this pkg list: `https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/allpackages` .  `dpkg -S /bin/udevadm` tells us is provided by `udev`which is on that list, which.  Also, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/usb-devices` tells us is provided by `usbutils` which is also on that list.  I also re-imaged an 18.04 host to validate this: they're there by default. And I did  state in my original answer how `udevadm` was used.

Comment: No prob.  I'm generally very meticulous when I post a solution, so I was really a bit stunned when you pulled me up.  Anyhoo, thanks for rescinding the initial down-grade!  When ever I get feedback on an  answer- downgrade or not- I'll always try to take it on-board and incorporate it

Comment: Keep up the good work. :)